# Add linear gradient to SVG circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to add a gradient I got from online to my SVG circle. This is my gradient

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
```

I am trying to add this gradient type to my circle instead of the "fill="yellow". I tried inserting the gradient in the code but nothing. Tried searching/playing around with it but, ended up with nothing. Here is my code

Codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdaMVR

```css
    .circlesvg{
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
      }        
       #firstCircle{
       animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
       -ms-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
       -webkit-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
       -moz-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
       -o-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
       transition-timing-function: linear;
       }
       @keyframes fadeAndScale{
       0%{
         z-index: 100;
         transform: scale(0);
         transform: translate(200px, 200px);
       }
       100%{
         z-index: 0;
         transform: scale(200);
    
    }
        }
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" class="circlesvg">
  <circle id="firstCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="40" fill="yellow"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use SVG's `<linearGradient>` element and then reference it as the fill:

```
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#a18cd1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fbc2eb"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle id="firstCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="40" fill="url(#gradient)"></circle>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbLaYy

Comment: I did that and the 100% part was stuck in the middle. Wow! Thank you :D